# system is working extremely slow with overheating

Tags: cpu, fan, overheating

My dell inspiron(core2duo ,3gb ram, integrated graphics chipset,ubuntu utopic ) is working exteremly slow. Both the cpus are clocking at  90% of their capacity while i am writing this question on chrome and with no other apps working.Everytime this happens i have to restart again.
It is really frustating.

> Here is the output from sensors

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +80.5°C  (crit = +93.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +79.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)  ALARM (CRIT)
Core 1:       +76.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

i8k-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Right Fan:      0 RPM
CPU:          +80.0°C  
temp2:        +61.0°C  
temp3:        +65.0°C  
temp4:        +65.0°C
```

going by fan RPM, I think it's dead. Any other pointers to where i need to check for problems?

Comment: You should clean the dust out and replace the thermal paste.  Verify the heatsink fan is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you solved this yourself.  CPU is reaching its throttling temperature due to a dead/dying/severly dirty fan.  Try first to blow all dust/dirt out of the fan.  You can use that canned air stuff; I usually use an air compressor with the regulator at 70-90psi and adjust flow with the blow gun.  From summer breeze to jackhammer on demand.

If all else fails, time to get a new fan.  Ebay usually has 'em.  You could put your laptop atop a fan atop some books while waiting.

Comment: Since I will be doing fan installation myself, I was thinking of overhauling the

Comment: sorry for my previous incomplete comment.                                              Since I will be doing fan installation myself, I wanted to know the parts which might get worn out and need replacement after long time(3-4 yrs) related to laptop cooling. So, i can change them.

Comment: Just the fan unit(s), really.  I would pick up a tiny bottle/packet of thermal paste in case you need to remove or re-seat the heat sink.